# Why do I get a bad instruction in the transaction?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, etherscan

Here is my withdraw dividend code :

```
  function WithdrawDividend(address) public {

    if (!_RestrictedFromDividend[address(msg.sender)]) {
        _SavedDividend[msg.sender] = _balances[address(this)].mul(_balances[address(msg.sender)]).div(100000000);  
        uint256 DividendsToBurn = _SavedDividend[msg.sender].mul(10).div(10000);
        uint256 DividendstoDividend = _SavedDividend[msg.sender].sub(DividendsToBurn);

        _balances[address(this)] = _balances[address(this)].sub(DividendstoDividend).sub(DividendsToBurn);
        _balances[msg.sender] = _balances[msg.sender].add(DividendstoDividend);
        _balances[address(0)] = _balances[address(0)].add(DividendsToBurn);

        _totalSupply = _totalSupply.sub(DividendsToBurn);
                _RestrictedFromDividend[address(msg.sender)] = true;
        ClaimTime[address(msg.sender)] = now;

        emit Transfer(address(this), msg.sender, DividendstoDividend);
        emit Transfer(address(this), address(0), DividendsToBurn);

    }
    else {
        emit Transfer(address(this), msg.sender, 0);
    }
```

}

I used to have it so that people had to put in their balance in a value section as well as their address but I couldn't figure out how to stop people from claiming dividends worth more than their balance, so I did this. But now I get a bad instruction error in the transaction and I don't see what is wrong. Everything seems perfect to me.

Comment: The bad instruction is for something else, which you have not posted here.

Comment: @goodvibration can I get a bit of clarification as to what you mean? It only occurred when I changed the code in question

Comment: Well, why don't you change it and stop it from occurring??? Or by the least, do some preliminary work to find out what's causing it (as you say, as a result of your changes), and post your findings here.